# Not Serializable: com/salesforce/api/fast/List$$lcom/salesforce/api/Schema/ChildRelationship$$r

Tags: apex, visualforce, issue

Not sure what this is/what this means. It compiles but when you open it in browser it gets killed once a button is clicked.

VF code :

```
<apex:commandButton value="Enter" action="{!verifyChildObject}" 
style="margin-left:10px" reRender="panel1"/>
```

Controller Function :

```
public void verifyChildObject() {
    //String field = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('searchField');

    System.debug('searchFieldChild - '+searchFieldChild);
    List<ChildRelationship> listOfChildObjs = SObjectType.Opportunity.getChildRelationships();
    listToMigrate = new List<ChildRelationship>();

    for(Integer i = 0; i < listOfChildObjs.size(); i++) {
        if(listOfChildObjs[i].getChildSObject() + ''==searchFieldChild) {
            childExists = true;
            listToMigrate.add(listOfChildObjs[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
    childExists = false;
    searchFieldChild = '';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
listToMigrate = new List<ChildRelationship>();
```

Specifically, describe results can't be stored in the view state. You'll have to convert them to another type of data if you want to show them on your page, such as a "wrapper" object.

Comment: Well, what I want to do is store the objects that the user has entered into that list and later on do some more manipulation w/the data stored in those child objects. If this isn't the correct approach, what would you recommend?

Comment: @user2582622 ChildRelationship isn't an editable object, so you probably just want a list of the appropriate type of child object (or the generic SObject type).